# Is there such a thing as a checkerboard subdivision?

Tags: mesh

Im looking for a way to subdivide any flat polygon in a grid pattern like this, in order to get more geometry for a cloth simulation:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There are algorithms that do this, but non I'm aware of in Blender. You can easily build one with geometry nodes

Comment: Knife Project a subdivided plane through the object

Comment: @AllenSimpson Perfect, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try this node setup here?

[image]

result:

[image]

of course you could delete the "height" vertices by z position so you got a flat result - i hope you can do this ;)

Explanation:

i am "misusing" the mesh boolean to get this effect. So first i create a grid (which does the "perfect" subdivision you wanna have). In order to do a mesh boolean, you need a volume. That's why i use the extrude node with flip faces, join and merge by distance. The flip faces node is necessary to get the "bottom" in the right direction. Just extrude would let the bottom "open". The merge by distance makes sure everything is connected right and the flipped face is really connected to the geometry (and not a "single" mesh island). The mesh boolean with intersect cuts the not used part away and you get the result you wanna have.

Comment: Cab you explain how the geometry node works?

Comment: i updated my answer